# How do I add a bean to Spring context in my library without breaking consumers who have their own instance of that bean?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a library which produces beans into a Spring context for use by clients. The beans I produce are configured by Spring. I need to add a new bean to my context in order to satisfy a dependency of a new bean I'm publishing. However, I believe some of my clients already have an instance of this bean and are autowiring it by type. So I have something like this:

```
// Code in my Library
@Component
public class PublicUtilityClass {

    // This is all new code in my library
    private NewDependency newDependency;

    public void newCapability() {
        newDependency.doNewThing();
    }

    @AutoWired
    public void setNewDependency(NewDependency newDependency) {
        this.newDependency = newDependency;
    }

    // Other library code omitted.
}
```

How can I use Spring to instantiate NewDependency and inject it into PublicUtilityClass without impacting customers who already have a NewDependency bean in their context?

Comment: The @ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation on your version of NewDependency might be what you want, if it's present in the version of spring that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at @Qualifier annotation. Qualifier allows you to have multiple instance of your bean